# O que significa essa variável?

Tags: python

Estou mexendo com python e pycuda, estudando códigos e etc e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida: O que ta acontecendo exatamente na segunda linha ?
service vai receber alguns atributos, na primeira linha, e até aí tudo okay. Entretanto na segunda linha service é uma função ?? Que papel o service ta desempenhando aí ?

```
service = getattr(entity, event["name"])
service(event["data"], event["tx"], event["txId"])
```

Em pycuda notei algo parecido também:

```
func = mod.get_function("doublify")
func(a_gpu, block=(4,4,1))
```

No código a cima eu tive a impressão de que "func" passará a realizar o papel de "doublify" (um trecho de código CUDA) e após recebe alguns argumentos. 
No primeiro exemplo, do "service", isso acabou ficando obscuro pra mim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acontece que métodos também são atributos de um objeto. Neste caso, o `event["name"]` possuirá como valor o nome de um método do objeto `entity` e quando faz:

```
service = getattr(entity, event["name"])
```

O objeto `service` será uma referência ao método. A título de exemplo, se `event['"name"]` possuísse o valor `start`, o código equivalente seria:

```
service = entity.start
```

A forma mais simples de se fazer esta atribuição de forma dinâmica é justamente através da função `getattr`. Portanto, na segunda linha:

```
service(event["data"], event["tx"], event["txId"])
```

Nada mais é que a chamada ao método passando três valores como parâmetros.

Quanto ao segundo exemplo, é difícil afirmar com certeza, pois depende da definição do objeto `mod` e do método `get_function`, mas tudo indica que é a mesma situação: retorna a referência à uma função e depois efetua sua chamada.

Veja um exemplo:

```
class Foo:
    def hello(self, name):
        print(f'Hello {name}')

foo = Foo()
func = getattr(foo, 'hello')

# print(type(func))  # <class 'method'>

func('world')  # Hello world
```